# Haskell Printing a hardcoded value from a function

Tags: haskell, winghci

I'm beginning my first exploration of functional programming with `Haskell`. I'm struggling a bit with printing a hardcoded value. I created a model representing a car and the gears it can go to. What I want to do is simply print my hardcoded `civicNinetyOne` when I call `printCar.` But I keep getting an error when I load the file. I posted the error below, it's an indentation error but from what I've read here at [LearnYouAHaskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses) that call function declaration is correct. Can someone point me to the cause of this issue? Thank you

**Error**

```
first_program.hs:10:1: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
   |
10 | printCar:: () -> Car    | ^
```

**Code**

```
data Car = Car{
   gears :: [String],
   currentGear :: String,
   brokeGears :: [String],
   shiftStroke:: Strokes
  }  

let civicNinetyOne = Car ["gear1", "gear2", "gear3", "gear4", "gear5"] "gear1" ["gear4"] [("gear1","pull", "gear2"), ("gear2","push", "gear3"), ("gear3","skipShift", "gear5")] 

printCar:: () -> Car
printCar = civicNinetyOne
```

Comment: What is the `()` doing here?

Comment: I read that the `()->` can be added in a function declaration to specify no parameters received. The value following the `->` is the return type. Is this not the case for Haskell?

Comment: No, here there is no parameter at all in your function declaration. `()` is the *unit type*.

Comment: The code you posted certainly has incorrect indentation (it also contains a fragment of an error message), but it's impossible to help you until you clean up the markdown in your question

Comment: @jberryman I updated the markdown and fixed the spacing. The code now looks exact like my .hs file.

Comment: Your immediate problem is `let`. It doesn't work the way you think it works. When you solve this, `()` should go. Perhaps together with `printCar`, as it's exactly the same as `civicNinetyOne`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printCar` takes an argument like any other function; it's argument type is `()`, which means there is only one value (also spelled `()`) that can be used to call it.

`civicNinetyOne`, on the other hand, is a value with type `Car`, not a function of type `() -> Car`, so cannot itself be assigned to `printCar`.

The correct definition is

```
printCar :: () -> Car
printCar () = civicNinetyOne
```

and it would be called as

```
> printCar ()
Car {gears = ["gear1","gear2","gear3","gear4","gear5"], currentGear = "gear1", brokeGears = ["gear4"], shiftStroke = [("gear1","pull","gear"),("gear2","push","gear3"),("gear3","skipShift","gear5")]}
```

---

For completeness, the `let` (as pointed out in the comments) is optional in recent versions of GHCi and required in older versions of GHCi, but it is *forbidden* in a module. (The interactive interpreter behaves somewhat like an implied `do` block.)

Comment: That’s definitely a mistake on my part then. I don’t want any paramters to be passed.  Once I get home I’ll update the code to remove the ()-> so it doesn’t accept any values

Comment: There's no such thing as a zero-argument function in Haskell; `printCar :: Car` would just be a value, like `civicNinetyOne`.